# Turning y axis upside down in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to turn the y axis upside down in matlab plots, so that the positive direction of the y axis, instead of up, points down ?

(I beg of you; please do not say, print it out, then turn the paper around ;-)

Comment: @Rook Please, note Ejo60's answer which I think is the best answer here now.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [`'YDir'` axes property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_XDir) can be either `'normal'` or `'reverse'`. By default it is `'normal'` for most plots, but some plots will automatically change it to `'reverse'`, such as the [`image`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) or [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) functions.

You can set the y-axis direction of an axes with either the [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) function or dot indexing (in newer MATLAB versions):

```
h = gca;  % Handle to currently active axes
set(h, 'YDir', 'reverse');
% or...
h.YDir = 'reverse';
```

I'm baffled by some of the other answers saying that the `'YDir'` property has somehow disappeared or is giving an error. I haven't seen any such behavior in versions of MATLAB from 2013, 2014, or 2016. There are only two potential pitfalls I came across:

- The property can't be set with a cell array, only a character string:

  ```
  >> set(gca, 'YDir', {'reverse'});
  Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set
  While setting property 'YDir' of class 'Axes':
  Invalid enum value. Use one of these values: 'normal' | 'reverse'.
  ```

  although this works:

  ```
  set(gca, {'YDir'}, {'reverse'});  % Property name is also a cell array
  ```
- The [`gca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) function can't be used interchangeably as a handle when performing dot indexing (which is why I first saved it to a variable `h` in the above example):

  ```
  >> gca.YDir
  Undefined variable "gca" or class "gca.YDir". 
  >> gca.YDir = 'reverse'  % Creates a variable that shadows the gca function
  gca = 
    struct with fields:

      YDir: 'reverse'
  ```

Finally, if you want some code that will toggle the `'YDir'` property no matter what its current state is, you can do this:

```
set(gca, 'YDir', char(setdiff({'normal', 'reverse'}, get(gca, 'YDir'))));
% or...
h = gca;
h.YDir = char(setdiff({'normal', 'reverse'}, h.YDir));
```

Comment: Beautiful ! (I really like matlab & SO combination, when rapidly doing a calculation :)

Comment: In case the plot corresponds to a 3D plot, the Y-axis is usually reversed by default (you can check it with `get(gca,'YDir')`. In that case, try: `set(gca,'YDir','normal');`

Answer (score 9):

The command

`axis ij`

Will also reverse the Y-axis (negative above x-axis; positive below).

Answer (score 6):

The solutions on the top of the stack did not work for me,

- `imagesc(x,y,data) % results in a flipped plot, the y axis is upside down`
- `set(gca,'YDir','reverse'); % gives an error`
- `axis ij; % still gives the flipped plot`

what did work was the following:

```
imagesc(x,y,data); axis xy;  % results in the correct plot
```

The `YDir` property has vanished in the matlab version (2013 and up) that I'm using.

Comment: I think this is the bets answer here; especially the last line `imagesc(time,y,matrix); axis xy;`. The commands `set('YDir','reverse');` and `set('YDir','normal');` exist in my Matlab 2016a. I do not understand what you mean that some property has vanished; probably, it has just changed.

Comment: To my knowledge, the `'YDir'` property has always been present, and setting it has never given me an error. This has worked for me in versions from 2013, 2014, and 2016.

Answer (score 2):

To update this answer, since it is still a popular Google result:
As of R2014a, the correct way to flip the Y axis is the following:

```
>> axis ij
```

This change can be reversed through the following command

```
>> axis ji
```

To flip the X or Z axes, do the following

`set(gca,'XDir','reverse');`

`set(gca,'ZDir','reverse');`

Personally, I think it would have been easier to keep the YDir option, but what do I know.

Comment: To my knowledge, the `'YDir'` property has always been present, and setting it has never given me an error. This has worked for me in versions from 2013, 2014, and 2016.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `YDir` (for some reason I cannot currently see) you can rotate the axes with [`view`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html). To turn the y-axis upside down, use

```
view(0,-90);
```