# Flip a plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am creating a plot with matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Can I flip the plot, making the y-axis inverted and all positive values negative and vice versa?

I know I can multiply by -1 and use `invert_yaxis` but I wonder if there is a function for flipping it without changing the values.

Comment: relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760614/turning-y-axis-upside-down-in-matlab

Comment: It sounds like  `plt.plot(x, -y)` would do exactly what you're looking for. What don't you like about *"changing the values"*?

Comment: Somehow I find your question hard to understand. On one hand you want to change the values (*making the y-axis inverted and all positive values negative and vice versa?*) and on the other hand you explicitly don't want to change the values (*I wonder if there is a function for flipping it without changing the values*). Could you clarify what the question is?

Answer (score 17):

Try the following function:

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Answer (score 2):

Inverting y limits from (-1.1,1.1) to (1.1,-1.1) with `plt.ylim` will do the trick...

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 63)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)  
plt.ylim(1.1,-1.1)
```

Note that (1.1,-1.1) are just 10% above and below `y.max()` and `y.min()` values, preventing the y line from touching the graph box. Note also that `x =np.arange(0, 5, .1)` does not cover a complete sinusoidal period, 2 pi radians... `x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 63)` solves this little issue with same `len(x)` provided by `np.arange(0, 5, .1)`.