# Flipping images and y-direction in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a figure that I'd like to plot 'stems' over based on certain arrays 'x', 'y' and 'z'. Say the image is called `image1`.

I have so far,

```
   stem3(x(n,:), y(n,:),10*z(n,:), 'm', 'LineWidth', 1,'Marker', 'none') 
   hold on 
   view([-10, -20])  
   imshow(flipud(image1)) 
   xlim([600, 1000])
```

however, when I run the script the stems don't go the way I'd like. They point in the negative direction, and multiplying z by -1 does nothing.

Comment: There are a number of solutions at [Turning y axis upside down in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1760614/5358968) you could try, otherwise you'll have to provide a [mcve], or perhaps some images explaining what you want and what you're getting.

Comment: if you first `imshow(image1)` and then `stem3(...)` does it work?